# Django shows empty field instead of ajax select widget (filter_horizontal)

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Django admin shows an empty field instead of "ajax select widget".

[image: admin.py]

Tried on the other project - in models with two m2m relations to completely equal models with different names. Works like a charm on one field, shows empty place on other. Any help or links?

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    """Companies - customers """
    title = models.CharField('Nosaukums', blank=False, max_length=200)
    is_costumer = models.BooleanField('Pasūtītājs', default=False)
    is_subcontractor = models.BooleanField('Apakšuzņēmējs', default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Uzņēmums'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Uzņēmumi'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Project(models.Model):
    """Projects"""

    number = models.IntegerField('Īsais numurs', blank=False, null=False)
    title = models.CharField('Nosaukums', blank=False, max_length=250)
    customers = models.ManyToManyField(Company, verbose_name='Pasūtītāji', blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Aktīvs', default=True)
    notes = models.TextField('Piezīmes', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Projekts'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Projekti'

    def costumer_list(self):
        list = "pasūtītāji"
        return list

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: ^^ No - no javascript errors.
^ - posted models.py

Answer (score 1):

Based on the model you posted above and the image of the admin file, your `filter_hoizontal` variable should be `filter_horizontal = ('customers',)` instead of `filter_horizontal = ('costumers',)` In other words, the spelling of customers differs between your model and admin files.

Comment: Thank you for the notice, but in this case that is not the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some of my m2m fields did not allow `form_horizontal`. I found that the only thing these specific fields had in common was that they were all for *categories*, in my native language this is *categorieën*, which happens to have an accent on the last *e*.

See my field definition below:

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField ( 
                              'FAQCategories',
               verbose_name = 'Categorieën',
               blank        = True,
             )
```

The problem here is that I did not tell python my string should be treated as Unicode. When I changed the `verbose_name` to `u'Categoriën'` it worked!

In retrospect this was very obvious to me but I hope this will help you or some else.. Define those strings properly, lesson learned!